# Error: 'tns preview' - Plugin not include

Tags: angular, nativescript, tns

I have a next error:

[Error_'tns previe'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3sOC.png)

[image]

and this is my package.json:

[pakage.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABg6x.png)

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: As the error reads, you can't use external plugins in preview app. If at all the plugin doesn't have any native dependency, you may able to use it by copying it to your app directory and use relative path to load the plugin.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand correctly what you say ... I have to install the plugin somewhere else? Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the error reads, you can't use any plugin with preview app except the predefined set of plugins those were packed with the Preview app, like nativescript ui plugins, background-http, camera etc.,

> The Preview app comes with a predefined set of NativeScript plugins. If your app utilizes a plugin that is not present in the Preview app, you will see a warning message and your app might not work as expected.

Source: [from docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/preview#command-limitations)