# How to buld npm dependencies in NativeScript in preview mode?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I use **NativeScript** and npm dependencies in `package.json`. When I launch application using command: `tns preview` it gives me ready application with error:

```
Plugin @ngx-translate/core is not included in preview app on device
```

My **package.json** is:

```
{
"dependencies": {
 "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0"
}
}
```

I guess NativeScript does not build npm dependencies in this mode, or these dependencies are not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nativescript Preview feature is limited to the already compiled modules. With this said, you cannot use Preview if you are including external dependencies and therefore you need to go with the `tns run` command.

Please see the following SO question as this might be a duplicate: [Error: 'tns preview' - Plugin not include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259494/error-tns-preview-plugin-not-include)

Edit: please check for @Manoj reply to this comment as I was very generic and he makes a good point regarding some things you may use in Preview.

Comment: You may still use any node modules those doesn't depend on Node or Browser based features & plugins those do not require native dependencies (pod / jar / aar), you will have to use relative path while requiring, you should be good then.